# Do you have any recommended plugins for Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-plugins

This is a copy of the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826/do-you-have-any-recommended-plugins-for-eclipse

But now is for netbeans (I'm not a eclipse lover. CTRL+TAB does not change pages.)

Please, I'm very curious.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend anyone who's Vi/Vim user the [jVi](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/) plugin, works great...

I also love the [PHP](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PHP), [Ruby](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ruby), [Subversion](http://subversion.netbeans.org/) and [Git](http://www.nbgit.org/) plugins...

Comment: as of 2013, most of this is incorported into Netbeans and no longer requires a plugin (e.g., subversion, git) or is an optional installation item (php).  jVi still is essential for vim users, and still works great; added link for [installing jVi via an update center](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38914/jvi-vi-vim-for-nb-7-0-update-center).

Answer (score 6):

The [SQE plugin](https://kenai.com/projects/sqe/pages/Home) (which integrates [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), and [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)) is extremely useful.

Comment: https://java.net/projects/sqe/

Answer (score 5):

The [Path Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676) plugin.

It adds four useful actions to Netbeans:

- **Copy Paths Action** Copy the full paths of the files/folder of selected node to the clipboard.
- **Explore Action** Launch the OS File Explorer
- **Shell On Path Action** Launch the OS shell
- **Edit Action** Launch the external editor

The webpage of the Path Tools plugin looks not very active, but it works in Netbeans 6.9.1 without problems (Works on My Machine).

Answer (score 2):

Thats not a good reason to not love Eclipse, IMHO.

Anyways, there are plenty, it depends what are you working on. I am using

- Spring, Spring MVC, Spring Webflow
- JSF, ICEFaces and Visual
- Subversion
- Groovy Grails
- C/C++
- Hibernate
- UML
- PHP
- Web Applications
- JBoss
- RESTful Webservices, SOA
- Java Doc
- Ant, Maven
- Python
- And few more, but these are notable.

Comment: The ANT task ANT-Eclipse can do that for you over there.

Answer (score 2):

I love the RegEx Plugin and I'm definitely installing the Twitter Integration plugin (http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=15661)

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Projects.

Build a project/"workspace" completely it's ANT file.

Much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

vi

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/vi-integration.html

Answer (score 1):

Enclojure is a good plug-in.  Very nice integration of the Clojure dynamic language into the Netbeans environment (including a REPL right in Netbeans!).

Answer (score 0):

Groovy plugin is great to! http://groovy.codehaus.org/NetBeans+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

http://coffeecokeandcode.blogspot.com/2008/05/special-copypaste.html

Its a copy and paste plugin, i share my code a lot with people sometimes when i'm writing word docs and stuff i need to copy the colour of the code. It also also you to copy it as html and css to paste into a web page.

http://openjdk.java.net/tools/svc/jconsole/
is pretty good for monitoring your programs, provides a few cool features for monitoring in general